# How do I DM a user when they join the server?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

And also make an embed which you have to react to with an emoji to get a verified role in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect user joining by an event:

```
const { Client } = require('discord');
const client = new Client();

client.on('guildMemberAdd', function(member) => {
    member.send('Welcome to my server!');
});

client.login('<token>');
```

Then, you can fetch a channel in the server and send the embed there:

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('<channel-id>');
channel.send(embed)
.then(message => {
    //reaction collector
});
```

For the reaction collector, please refer to the [djs guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors).